# $location.path(...) does not update page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to move to a user's main page after successful login. 
The browser's address bar is correctly updated by calling $location.path(), but the page is not reloaded.

I know it's a kind of a common problem, with several potential causes.

- I think I am correctly inside angular lifecycle, since successful authentication is either triggered by an $http.post response or simulated via and angular $timeout (neither method works)
- Adding $scope.apply() does not help anyway
- Setting for example $location.absUrl('http://google.com') instead has no effect at all.

Here is the login controller:

```
var swControllers = angular.module('swControllers', []);

swControllers.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'authentication',
    function($scope, $location, authentication) {
        authentication.ClearCredentials();

        $scope.login = function () {
            $scope.dataLoading = true;
            authentication.Login($scope.email, $scope.password, function(response) {
                $scope.dataLoading = false;
                if (response.success) {
                    authentication.SetCredentials($scope.email, $scope.password);
                    $location.path('userHome');
                    //$location.absUrl('http://google.com');
                    //$scope = angular.element(document).scope();
                    //$scope.$apply();

                } else {
                    $scope.error = response.message;
                    // $scope.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };
}]);
```

I have more general architectural concerns: is it cleaner to rely on ngRoute for this kind of stuff? Does this mean I'm limited to a single-page app?

Because I'm using Express + jade template views on the server side, and currently login page and userHome reside on two different templates.

I'm a bit dazzled by the interplay between server-side and client-side routing...

Comment: can we get a look at the controller? Are you injecting the `$location` service?